# What does "Disk is OK, one attribute failed in the past" mean?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I have installed new Seagate hard disk to my old system and installed Ubuntu 14.04. I checked disk status using `gksudo gnome-disks` and resulted in `Disk is OK, one attribute failed in the past`. I did not get any proper links for this message. 
Can someone tell what does it mean ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=154894) it says:

> You're reading the SMART data. Disk is ok means no bad sectors. One issue in the past is usually an overtemp and it's no big deal.

So run `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX`, where `X` is your device letter which I think should be `a`, so that would be `/dev/sda`. Look through that to see if any issues had occurred that is worth noting, but I doubt.

Comment: What you say is correct, but if I had a brand new disk that was failing, especially on a history-type parameter, I would wonder how new my disk really was, and consider returning it.

Answer (score 0):

Worth checking the listings in the SMART Data & Self-Tests (Disks or Disk Utility software) for the 'Power-On Hours' just to be sure it is new. I was once sent a supposedly new drive that had already clocked up a couple of months.